# Get most common value over group by for multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Customer    SiteNumber  DeviceNumber    Address         ValueA      ValueB
100         1           T1              123 Main St     50          60  
100         1           T2              123 Main St     50          null
100         1           T3              null            50          60
100         3           T1              27 Front St     100         null    
100         3           T2              null            null        null
100         3           T3              27 Front St     100         60
200         1           T1              222 Main St     40          60  
200         1           T2              222 Main St     40          null
200         1           T3              null            40          60
```

The query is to summarize some data.  Essentially I want to know for each site, grouped by customer, What the most common address is (excluding null), and the most common ValueA and Value B are, excluding nulls.  They don't need to be from the same row, just the same group by Customer, SiteNumber.  In theory these values should be the same on all the devices, but sometimes one of them has a typo, or the data is missing (null), so I just need to know reasonably, what the site address is, and I figured majority rules is an easy way to do it.

I've tried to search but I'm not entirely sure what terms to search for.  I did [an example which worked for one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032529/select-value-of-largest-groups-most-common-values-in-bridge-table-in-t-sql) however I could only get it to return all three columns for a record which had the most common address.

I'd like the output to look like this:

```
Customer    SiteNumber  Address         ValueA      ValueB
100         1           123 Main St     50          60  
100         3           27 Front St     100         60  
200         1           222 Main St     40          60
```

I don't have an example of what isn't working, because I'm not even sure how to get going on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bit chatty, but one potential solution is:

```sql
SELECT  Customer,SiteNumber
,   MAX(CASE WHEN col1Rank = 1 THEN Address END) AS Address
,   MAX(CASE WHEN col2Rank = 1 THEN ValueA END) AS ValueA
,   MAX(CASE WHEN col3Rank = 1 THEN ValueB END) AS ValueB
FROM    (
    
    SELECT  *
    ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Customer, SiteNumber ORDER BY AddrCnt DESC, Address) AS col1Rank
    ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Customer, SiteNumber ORDER BY ValueACnt DESC, ValueA) AS col2Rank
    ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Customer, SiteNumber ORDER BY ValueBCnt DESC, ValueB) AS col3Rank
    FROM    (
            select  *
            ,   COUNT(Address) OVER(PARTITION BY Customer, SiteNumber, Address) AddrCnt
            ,   COUNT(ValueA) OVER(PARTITION BY Customer, SiteNumber, ValueA) ValueACnt
            ,   COUNT(ValueB) OVER(PARTITION BY Customer, SiteNumber, ValueB) ValueBCnt
            from
            (
                VALUES  (100, 1, N'T1', '123 Main St', 50, 60)
                ,   (100, 1, N'T2', '123 Main St', 50, NULL)
                ,   (100, 1, N'T3', NULL, N'50', N'60')
                ,   (100, 3, N'T1', '27 Front St', 100, NULL)
                ,   (100, 3, N'T2', NULL, NULL, NULL)
                ,   (100, 3, N'T2', NULL, NULL, NULL)
                ,   (100, 3, N'T3', '27, Front St', 100, 60)
                ,   (200, 1, N'T1', '222 Main St', 40, 60)
                ,   (200, 1, N'T2', '222 Main St', 40, NULL)
                ,   (200, 1, N'T3', NULL, N'40', N'60')
            ) t (Customer,SiteNumber,DeviceNumber,Address,ValueA,ValueB)
        ) x
    ) x
GROUP BY Customer, SiteNumber
ORDER BY Customer, SiteNumber
```

The main idea is that you want to rank every column separately by most occurrences. For that we first do `COUNT(columnX) OVER`, then `ROW_NUMBER() OVER` and finally a little bit of conditional aggregation to get the most occurring row.

An important detail is that `COUNT(*)` would count NULLs ahead of real values, which we don't want, therefor I use `COUNT(ColumnX)`.

An exercise for the reader is to prioritize matching combination of data rows in case of ties

Output:

| Customer | SiteNumber | Address | ValueA | ValueB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | 123 Main St | 50 | 60 |
| 100 | 3 | 27 Front St | 100 | 60 |
| 200 | 1 | 222 Main St | 40 | 60 |